# "Error: Could not find or load main class Average" When Using Referenced Assembly in Java Code

Tags: java, eclipse

The following code works fine in Eclipse (it is saved in a source file Average.java)

I added reference to stdlib.jar in Eclipse and it builds and runs fine in Eclipse

public class Average {

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double sum = 0.0;
    int cnt =0;
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
    {
        sum +=StdIn.readDouble();
        cnt++;
    }
    double avg =  sum / cnt;
    StdOut.printf("Average is %.5f\n", avg);
    System.out.println("Hi");
    }

}
```

I wanted to try and run it from command line. I was able to compile it using:
"c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\javac" -classpath "C:\Users\\Documents\IntroCS\stdlib.jar" Average.java

However when running Average using:

java -classpath "C:\Users\\Documents\IntroCS\stdlib.jar" Average

I get the error: "Error: Could not find or load main class Average"

I found that if I comment the lines which contain StdIn and StdOut which is in the referenced assembly, this runs fine from the command line.

I wanted to understand what is going on here and what may be required to allow this to run from the command line along with the referenced assembly.

The class file which is created by Eclipse also returns the same error when run from the command line. Some details on how Eclipse works vs. how the command line execution runs will be highly appreciated. I am new to Java even though slightly more experienced in C++, vb.net, C# and Windows world in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-classpath "C:\Users\\Documents\IntroCS\stdlib.jar"` tells Java to look in stdlib.jar for classes.

stdlib.jar doesn't have a class called "Average", so Java can't find it there.

You need to tell it to look in the IntroCS directory as well (if that's where your Average.class file is), using:

```
java -classpath "C:\Users\Documents\IntroCS\stdlib.jar;C:\Users\Documents\IntroCS" Average
```

Comment: You could also just use `.` for the current directory.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Average was not in the same directory but in the directory from which java command was being invoked. Reference to this directory is not needed when an external library is not referenced however when an external library is referenced we must explicitly specify path of the class being run! Thanks.

Comment: "c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\java" -classpath "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\IntroCS\stdlib.jar;." Average
works perfectly too. Thanks!!